# Showing that $2n$ is in the set EVEN from a recursive definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define the set EVEN (positive even integers) with two rules:

$1$) $2$ is in even

$2$) if $x,y \in $ EVEN then $x+y \in $ EVEN

I want an efficient method for proving $2n$ is in EVEN. My idea thus far is to 
first show that $floor(log_2(2n))$ is in even by adding up the highest powers of $2$ already shown to be in EVEN, and then count upwards in increments of $2$ until the number is reached. For instance take $n=7$, then

1)$2$ is in Even

2)$2 + 2 = 4$ is in Even

3)$4+4 = 8$ is in Even

And now add $2$ continually until I get to $14$. This method can take at most 
$floor(log_2(2n)) + (floor(log_2(2n))-1)) $ steps and I am not sure it is ideal. Any tips for optimization or other ideas (including binary representation) appreciated.

Comment: Induction?  $2$ is in EVEN and, inductively, $2n-2=2(n-1)$ is in EVEN.

Comment: @lulu it's the set of positive even integers, so the minus sign isn't included in the induction. Also I think I am supposed to show the rules as they are being applied like in what I wrote, rather than an inductive argument.

Comment: Not following.  I don't believe you can show this without induction.  It's an inductive definition.

Comment: @lulu you are right, sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea about using addition to carry it forward, but the method you've chosen may be a bit hard to describe generally. Instead, I recommend adding $2$ each time, rather than sometimes doubling.

Suppose for some positive integer $n$ that we want to prove $2n$ is even. You know that $2=2\cdot1$ is even by definition, so suppose that $n>1.$ If you know that $2k$ is even for some positive integer $k,$ then $2(k+1)=2k+2$ is even. After applying this process (adding $2$) $n-1$ times, you'll have proved that $2n$ is even.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make the question clear. I am supposed to apply the rules repeatedly until I show that 2n is in the set, it's more of an algorithm than an inductive proof I believe.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to accommodate a more algorithmic approach.

Comment: Ok! I understand this argument now, I don't think I did a moment ago... This is brilliant! Thanks so much.

Comment: You're very welcome! Another (arguably faster, but more complicated) method is to start from the binary expansion of $2n,$ which we can prove (from the binary expansion of $n$) can be written as $$\sum_{j=1}^k2^{i_j},$$ with $k$ a positive integer, and the numbers $i_j$ forming an increasing finite sequence of positive integers. Start with the fact that $2=2^1$ is even. Then apply the fact (if $2^i$ is even, then $2^{i+1}=2^i+2^i$ is even) $i_k-1$ times. At this point, we know that each power of $2$ in the binary expansion is even....

Comment: .... Thus, the sum of the first two terms will be even, so the sum of the first three will be even, and so on, until we've proved that $2_n$ is even. All told, this takes $i_k+k-1$ steps, which I leave to you to rewrite in terms of $n.$

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it only takes $i_k+k-1$ steps **if you already know** the binary expansion of $2n.$ If you have to find it, first, then those steps will need to be taken int account.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical Induction is the key.

for $n=1$, we know $2(1) =2$ is even.

If true for $ n$, then $2(n+1)=2n+2$, even plus even is even.

Thus it is true for every $n$

Answer (score 0):

Purely algorithmic approach Initialize the result to `res = 0` then compute the powers of two until `n == res` also & is the bitwise AND

```
powTwo=2;
while(n != res)
{
   if(n & powTwo) res += powTwo;
   powTwo += powTwo; // Or binary shift powTwo=powTwo<<1;
}
```

This takes $\log_2(n)$ steps to get from $0$ to $n$ using your recursive definition. It's like looking at the binary representation of $2n$ for $14$ it is $1110$ so to get $1110$ you add $10+100+1000=2+4+8$. Also this could be easily converted to a recursive function.